# Finding percentages from the count operator results in kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have two queries that find the total number of distinct occurrences of using the count operator. I want to be able to then display percentage of total distinct occurrences of those faults. So I tried dividing DistinctRB by Distinct Faults to give me a ratio.

```
let DistinctFaults = materialize (FaultView
|distinct ha, Ba, ga
|count);
let DistinctRB = materialize (FaultView
|where RB =~ "yes"
|distinct ha, Ba,ga
|count);
print  FaultRB / DistinctFaults
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this (using `toscalar()`):

```
let DistinctFaults = toscalar(
    FaultView
    | distinct ha, Ba, ga
    | count
);
let DistinctRB = toscalar(
    FaultView
    | where RB =~ "yes"
    | distinct ha, Ba, ga
    | count
);
print result = FaultRB / DistinctFaults
```

or, if an estimation of the distinct count (using `dcountif()`) is an option:

```
FaultView
| summarize result = dcountif(strcat_delim("_", ha, Ba, ga), RB =~ "yes") / 
            dcount(strcat_delim("_", ha, Ba, ga))
```